# How to automatic construct datetime format with zeros in last workday

Tags: datetime, sas, format

I'm trying to create a macro to return the last workday at midnight in sas to filter in oracle databases.

I already find the workday part, but I'm in trouble to convert to datetime.

I tried to combine sysfunc/qsysfunc/eval with some datetime functions of sas but no one returned

```
%macro weekdays;
 %let data_proc = %SYSFUNC(TODAY());

 %if %sysfunc(weekday(&data_proc.)) eq 2 %then
      %do;
            %let data_return= %sysfunc(intnx(DAY,&data_proc.,-3));
      %end;

 %else %if %sysfunc(weekday(&data_proc.)) eq 1 %then
      %do;
            %let data_return= %sysfunc(intnx(DAY,&data_proc.,-2));
      %end;
 %else
      %do;
            %let data_return = %sysfunc(intnx(DAY,&data_proc.,-1));
      %end;

 %PUT >>>>> &data_return.;
%mend;

%weekdays;
```

The workdays macro is returning >>>>> 21811

And I need that the final return to be in format '12SEP2019:00:00:00'dt

Thanks

Comment: Did you try simplifying your logic to use the WEEKDAY interval instead of the DAY interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number 21,811 is the value for the date '19SEP2019'd.  So just apply the DATE9 format to convert it.

```
%let date_return="%sysfunc(putn(&date_return,date9)):00:00:00"dt;
```

Note that you can also use the optional second argument to the %SYSFUNC() function to tell it how to format the function results.

```
%let data_return = %sysfunc(intnx(DAY,&data_proc.,-1),date9);
```

Then you just need to tack on the `:00:00:00` suffix to make it look like datetime value instead of date value.

Note that you probably can eliminate most of this logic and just let INTNX() find the right day for you by using the WEEKDAY interval instead of DAY interval.

```
%put "%sysfunc(intnx(weekday,%sysfunc(today())-1,0),date9):00:00:00"dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

The macro is not returning anything.  Macros do not return values, they perform processing and may or may not generate additional source code (codegen) that is injected into the submit stream for the executor.

If you need the value `'12SEP2019:00:00:00'dt` to be generated by your macro, you will need to use `%str` in constructing the codegen emitted.

```
%macro weekdays;
  %local today datecomp;

  %let today = %SYSFUNC(TODAY());

  %if %sysfunc(weekday(&today.)) eq 2 %then
    %let datecomp = %sysfunc(intnx(DAY,&today.,-3));
  %if %sysfunc(weekday(&today.)) eq 1 %then
    %let datecomp = %sysfunc(intnx(DAY,&today.,-2));
  %else
    %let datecomp = %sysfunc(intnx(DAY,&today.,-1));

  /* emit datetime literal from datecomp, nominally considered a return by functional language programmers */
  %str(%')%sysfunc(putn(&datecomp,date9.)):00:00:00%str(%'DT)
%mend;

%put %weekdays;
%let somedatetimeliteral=%weekdays;
%put &=somedatetimeliteral;
```

You can also use `PROC FCMP` to create a user defined function that does actually return a value.